# Using Perl, what's the best way to prune the first half of a file?

Tags: perl

My apologies for my ignorance, but I am VERY new to Perl and in need of some immediate assistance....

I have a file containing "Historical" data, and I know that the records are comma delimited. This file keeps growing and growing as history goes on, of course. So using Perl, I want to prune the file of the data, since it's the oldest. This doesn't need to be an exact science. I figured I'd do something like the following:

- Count the number of commas in the file and divide by 2 (to find the halfway point)
- So, for example if there a 100 records (and, therefore, 99 comma delimeters), the comma count is 99
- Then I'd divide by 2 to get the approximate halfway point (rounding up), which would be 46 in this example
- Then delete all records prior to the 46th comma (including the comma, so that the file won't start with a comma).
- And then save my newly pruned Historical Data file.

Here's a very small sample file layout with Comma Delimeters:

```
20121130092403000Server1::RedHat   1.2.3.4(1234),20121130092503000Server2::RedHat   5.6.7.8(1234),20121130092603000Server3::SUSE   9.8.7.6(9876),20121130092703000Server4::WindowsXP   5.6.7.8(6543)
```

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: Are all the records on the same line?

Comment: Have you even searched google, I know there are a lots of topics covering how to read a file?

Comment: Not sure why the downwotes?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Sounds like each record is separated by comma, so your approach seems to be okay. IDK, why you are getting downvotes. I am not a perl guy so cant help though.

Answer (score 1):

What the "fastest, most efficient way" is might be a different question. This is a typical way to do something like that:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = ",";
my @file = <DATA>;
say "Number of records: " . @file;
my $half = int((@file/2)+0.5);
say "Last half of records ($half):";
say @file[$half .. $#file];

__DATA__
20121130092403000Server1::RedHat   1.2.3.4(1234),20121130092503000Server2::RedHat   5.6.7.8(1234),20121130092603000Server3::SUSE   9.8.7.6(9876),20121130092703000Server4::WindowsXP   5.6.7.8(6543),
```

Note that the DATA file handle is used for demonstration here. You can simply change `<DATA>` to `<>` to make it use file arguments instead.

This will be somewhat less efficient because the file is read into memory, and that will consume memory, which can be costly for large files. An alternative is to simply run through the file and count the records, then reopen the file to do the printing. E.g.:

```
my $file = shift;
local $/ = ",";
open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!;
my $count;
while (<$fh>) { $count++ }
$count = int(($count/2)+0.5);
open $fh, "<", $file or die $!;
while ($count-- > 0) { <$fh> };
while (<$fh>) { print }
```

And of course these outputs need to be redirected, e.g. like so:

```
perl script.pl oldfile > newfile
```

You may also like the [`Tie::File`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aFile) module. E.g.:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;

my $file = shift;
tie @array, 'Tie::File', $file or die $!;
my $half = int((@array/2)+0.5);
splice @array, 0, $half;
untie @array;
```

Note that the effects of this is irreversible, so make backups before you try it. It is supposedly efficient even for large files, and does not read the file into memory.

Comment: These files can get rather large, which is why I was looking for the most efficient way of pruning. If I schedule this new Perl script to run daily, then that'll keep the file size down somewhat. I'll start playing with this on a small file for starters.

Comment: Perhaps you should look into something like a log rotation module instead. I believe *nix does that sort of thing automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to remove from the beginning of a file. It's only from end of a file. To effectively remove from the beginning of a file, one must rewrite the entire file (for example, by creating a new file with the part to keep, then renaming the new file over the old file).

Comment: So what's the fastest, most efficient way to do that?

Comment: Of what, printing to a file?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like I need to use a WHILE loop to get the number of commas, and then divide that number by 2(rounding) to find the approximate halfway point. Then use another WHILE loop that writes out the rest of the records. But I was hoping there was a very quick way to find that halfway point and then just dump the second half of the file to another file. Then I can just rename it as you mentioned.

Comment: You said how you wanted to do that part. You asked about pruning the beginning of a file. (Note that you could use the size of the file rather than the number of commas as a guide. Then use [`seek`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) to find the middle of the file.)

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on how and when data is added to your file. Is data added once a day? once an hour? continuously? on an manual basis? Can you prevent new data from being added to the file while you re-construct the data file? Is the file continuously held open by the writing process or is it re-opened every time new data is added?

A better approach is to write new data to a new file. For instance, if you want to manage data on a per-day basis, have the writer process write new data to a file based on the current date. E.g. data written on 2012-12-11 gets written to the file `data-2012-12-11`, etc.

Then you can manage your data by simply deleting files. To iterate over all of you data, you can use perl's globbing capability:

```
@ARGV = glob("data-*");
while (<>) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: That would be a good way to handle it - unfortunately, I have zero control over the writer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether all of the records are in one line (so that your .csv resembles a list) or multiple lines (so that your .csv resembles a table).

If it's the former, the approach you outlined would work fine.  This does the trick:

```
use strict;
use POSIX;

my $filename = "somecsvfilename.csv";
open (IN, "<", $filename);
my $fulltext;
while (<IN>) {
    chomp;
    $fulltext .= $_;
}
close IN;

my @data_segments = split(",", $fulltext);
my $num_commas = @data_segments;
my $num_to_delete = floor($num_commas/2);

open (OUT, ">", $filename);
my $i = $num_to_delete;
while ($i < $num_commas) {
    print OUT $data_segments[$i];
    if ($i != ($num_commas - 1)) {print OUT ","}
    $i++;
}
close OUT;
```

If your data is in fact a table, you'll want to use something like Text::CSV and just delete the first half of the rows array prior to outputting the data.  You may want to consider keeping the first row, as it may contain header data...without seeing your input it's hard to say what would be best.